# Xamarin Forms Android: Asset File not Found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I'm attempting to use the Xamarin Plugin [Simple Audio Player](https://blog.xamarin.com/adding-sound-xamarin-forms-app/) to play a sound when a button is pressed. The instructions say place the audio file in the Android project *Assets* folder, and set the Build Action to Android Asset. I've done that; however, whenever I tried to run the app on my phone via Xamarin Live Player, the button click generates a File not Found exception.

For what it's worth, the iOS version of the app works as expected; the audio file plays when I press the button.

Is there any way to further debug the file location, check that it is actually getting copied over to the phone in the correct place? What else can I do in Xamarin to ensure a proper build?

Comment: Does the filename have any `-` dashes? I know that resources cannot contain any, but not sure about assets. Also, I believe the filename should be all lowercase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Android Assets.Open throws FileNotFound exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620901/xamarin-android-assets-open-throws-filenotfound-exception)

Comment: No, no dashes. I had underscores first, then removed all non-alpha characters just to be safe. :)

Answer (score 0):

Live player has still some limitation to be aware of.

If your targeting platform is iOS and you have been using assets catalogs, it won't work. Same story for keeping files in resources within PCL for any targeting platform.

[Xamarin Live Player limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations?tabs=android)

Hope it helps.